# Delete an element from the code using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying Jquery and now I have a problem.
I want to remove an element from my webpage. So, when I press the delete button - the big element must disappear. Using the JQ I have written something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".delete").click(function(){
          $(this).parents(".block").animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow");
      })
    });
```

It have worked fine until I didn't add subdiv, or answer. And how the application must works now? I press the delete button and it must remove current block.

```
<div class = "block">
<div class = "postbuttons">
    <img src = "img/delete-icon.png" class = "delete"></a>
    <img src = "img/edit-icon.png" class = "edit"></a>
</div>

<div class = "postinfo">
    <span class = "author"><a href = "#">Da Monkey</a> wrote:</span> <span class = "date">on <span>13.13.13</span></span>
</div>

<div class = "post">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, voluptate, unde, impedit iste sint assumenda consequatur ipsum nesciunt</p>
    <a class = "answerlink" href = "#">Answer</a>
</div>

<div class = "answer">  
    <div class = "postbuttons">
        <img src = "img/delete-icon.png" class = "delete"></a>
        <img src = "img/edit-icon.png" class = "edit"></a>
    </div>              
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, numquam, culpa, omnis explicabo ut asperiores ipsam porro alias quisquam nisi iste non a maiores! Nulla odio unde dolorum officia vero.  </p>
    <div class = "answerinfo">
        - <a href = "#">Macaque</a> on <span>13.13.13</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you didn't understand me here the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEAvb.png)

Comment: if you add a class block to the answer div it works  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8VHR5/2/) edit: oh and you also need first()

Comment: Are you wanting to hide the element or remove it? Those are two very different things and both possible with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding the container of the container of the delete button, which will work regardless of its class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".delete").click(function(){
          $(this).parents(".postbuttons").parent().animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow");
      })
    });
```

Comment: Hi, this answer would be better if you would explain what you're doing in the code.  Code-only answers don't necessarily help the OP (and others) improve their understanding of the process.

Comment: Well, I used Google and found what this code is doing. But it's better when someone explain how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Respect to the funcionality:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $(".delete").click(function(){
              $(this).closest(".block").animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow");
          });
        });
```

you should use closest instead of parents because it stop once it has found the first math and parents travels to the root of the dom. Also if you dont need the block anymore you can remove it with the jquery method remove(), after tue animation ended with a callback function.

Also you are missing some semicolons, and tags

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".delete").click(function(){
          $(this).parents(".block").animate({ opacity: 'hide' }, "slow");
      })   // here needs a semicolon
    });
```

Missing tags

```
<div class = "block">
<div class = "postbuttons">
    <img src = "img/delete-icon.png" class = "delete"></a> <--! missing <a> -->
    <img src = "img/edit-icon.png" class = "edit"></a> <--! missing <a> -->
</div>

<div class = "postinfo">
    <span class = "author"><a href = "#">Da Monkey</a> wrote:</span> <span class = "date">on <span>13.13.13</span></span>
</div>

<div class = "post">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, voluptate, unde, impedit iste sint assumenda consequatur ipsum nesciunt</p>
    <a class = "answerlink" href = "#">Answer</a>
</div>

<div class = "answer">  
    <div class = "postbuttons">
        <img src = "img/delete-icon.png" class = "delete"></a>  <--! missing <a> -->
        <img src = "img/edit-icon.png" class = "edit"></a>   <--! missing <a> -->
    </div>              
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga, numquam, culpa, omnis explicabo ut asperiores ipsam porro alias quisquam nisi iste non a maiores! Nulla odio unde dolorum officia vero.  </p>
    <div class = "answerinfo">
        - <a href = "#">Macaque</a> on <span>13.13.13</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope I was Useful.

Comment: Also, it's obliviously that I'll add ajax queries for this operation. How should I find required element? I assigned for all message blocks id. Like this: <div class = "block" id = "5">. And the delete button is just images. Have you another ideas about this issue?

Comment: I just saw the image you posted, you dont need ids, simply add the class "block" to the answer div, like this fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eG4jU/)